# In VueJS, v-for doesn't create discrete items when new data is assigned

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently, when I have a `v-for` loop like this:

```
<li v-for="record in records">
    <my-vue-list-item :vue-title="record.title"></my-vue-list-item>
</li>
```

and I update the data driving the `v-for` (i.e. assign a new value to `records`), it doesn't actually create new list items based on the new data. It just updates some of the properties on the list item components components.

Here is [a JSFiddle illustrating what I'm talking about](https://jsfiddle.net/ahxf44jk/20/). Try expanding one of the buttons (e.g. click "Expand Apple"), then click on "Set 2" to see that even when the list items switch, the component stays expanded.

What's the recommended way of getting around this behavior? I want each new list item (when the data is swapped out) to appear like new. (In the fiddle example, which I load a new set, it should not be already expanded.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the Vue components know that the item is different. As far as they know, they're still rendering the same element index from the same list.

You can do this by specifying the `key` in your `v-for` iterator...

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahxf44jk/21/